# Why is `overflow-x` causing my list items to vertically overlap?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, overflow

I am creating a text box with a drop-down selection list, and for whatever reason when I try to apply `overflow-x: hidden` to the items in the selection list, they overlap within the list. I have no idea what could be causing this, and it's driving me insane.

Here is the selector without `overflow-x` applied:

```css
.desktop-expandable-select {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
}

.results-wrapper {
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.results {
    background: #eeeeff;
    border: solid 0.1rem blue;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 22rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.result {
    transition: background 0.125s;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    color: black;
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

.result:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class='desktop-expandable-select'>
  <input>
  <div class='results-wrapper'>
    <div class='results'>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas erat sed malesuada varius. Suspendisse convallis eu diam eget porttitor. Fusce mollis pellentesque lectus, quis rutrum nisi vulputate hendrerit. Etiam tincidunt auctor pretium. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc vitae lorem nec enim bibendum congue. Sed enim purus, vehicula eu condimentum a, luctus et nibh. Phasellus lorem quam, consectetur vitae ornare eu, varius ac erat. Fusce quis enim ullamcorper, commodo urna ac, sollicitudin dui. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. </p>
```

And here it is again with `overflow-x` applied:

```css
.desktop-expandable-select {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
}

.results-wrapper {
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.results {
    background: #eeeeff;
    border: solid 0.1rem blue;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 22rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.result {
    transition: background 0.125s;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    color: black;
    background: none;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

.result:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class='desktop-expandable-select'>
  <input>
  <div class='results-wrapper'>
    <div class='results'>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
      <button class='result'>This is a selectable item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas erat sed malesuada varius. Suspendisse convallis eu diam eget porttitor. Fusce mollis pellentesque lectus, quis rutrum nisi vulputate hendrerit. Etiam tincidunt auctor pretium. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc vitae lorem nec enim bibendum congue. Sed enim purus, vehicula eu condimentum a, luctus et nibh. Phasellus lorem quam, consectetur vitae ornare eu, varius ac erat. Fusce quis enim ullamcorper, commodo urna ac, sollicitudin dui. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. </p>
```

Is it maybe because I also have `overflow-y` applied to the wrapper? I have to have some way to scroll the list in case there's too many items, but I can't figure out how to do that *and* truncate items if they're too long.

Comment: You have a max-height on results so the flex works to that. It isn’t enough space to get the children in fully.

Comment: That's the thing though, the children shouldn't be trying to fit in there. I have an `overflow-y` on `results` so that it scrolls vertically, and it does when `overflow-x` isn't applied.